# Use variable in style, without spaces

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-views

I have this code:

```
<div class="testexample" style="top:@example.Y px"></div>
```

I thought this would work fine, but the browser is complaining about the spaces in the style.

[image]

(Invalid property value)

Any ideas to solve this?

Comment: Do you have to have px in the string? Can't px be a part of the variable?

Comment: `style="top:@(example.Y)px"`

Comment: @Reality-Torrent the values are coming directly out of the database, so no.

Comment: @StephenMuecke why do you (almost) always post the answer in a commant? I've seen this multiple times in my, and other questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put the whole string inside an [expression syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor#explicit-razor-expressions) like this:

```
<div class="testexample" style="top:@(example.Y + "px")"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of this you can use it in `calc`

```
<div class="testexample" style="top:calc( @example.Y )px"></div>
```

or

```
<div class="testexample" style="top:(@example.Y)px"></div>
```